# My first jQuery plugin -- Heftybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I'm getting started with my first official jQuery plugin, and I'm just turning now looking for input. I want to know what I'm doing wrong or right so far and if everything is being developed in a manner that won't cause issue down the road. With no further adieu:

```
$.fn.heftyBox = function(args) {
    if ($(this).length) {
    //Set up defaults
    var a    =  $.extend({
        type   :  "checkbox",
        width  :  "auto",
        height :  ($(this).innerHeight() > 150) ? $(this).innerHeight() : 150
    }, args);

    //Gather original attributes, convert DOM, then reassgign attributes
    var attributes = $(this)[0].attributes;
    var optionsHTML = $(this).html();
    $(this).after('<ul id="tmpul">' + optionsHTML + '</ul>');
    $(this).remove();
    var ul = $('#tmpul')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        $(ul).attr(attributes[i].name, attributes[i].value);
    }


    //Convert options to checkbox or radios
    var options = $(ul).children('option');
    var name = $(ul).attr('name');
    $(ul).removeAttr('name');
    var f = 0;
    $.each(options, function(key, option) {
        var itemAttributes = $(this)[0].attributes;
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        var label = $(this).text();
        var selected = $(this).attr('selected') ? "checked" : ''
        selected += $(this).attr('disabled') ? " disabled" : ''
        var newLi;
        $(this).replaceWith(newLi = $('<li ' + selected + '><input type="' + a.type + '" id="option_' + name + '_' + f + '" name="' + name + '" value="' + value + '" ' + selected + '/><label for="option_' + name + '_' + f + '">' + label + '</label></li>') )
        for (var i = 0; i < itemAttributes.length; i++) {
            $(newLi).children('input').attr(itemAttributes[i].name, itemAttributes[i].value);
        }
        f++;
    })

    //Add Filter Box
    $(ul).before('<input id="' + name + '_filter" class="list_filter" />');
    var list = $(ul).children('li');
    var filter = $('#' + name + '_filter');
    filterBox($(filter), list);

    //Contain it all
    $(filter).before('<div class="heftyBox" id="' + name + '_container"></div>');
    var container = $('#' + name + '_container');
    $(filter).appendTo($(container));
    $(ul).appendTo($(container));

    //Select all box for checkboxes
    if (a.type == "checkbox") {
        $(filter).after($('<a href="#">Select All</a>').bind('click', function() {
            var checkboxes = $(this).next('ul').find('input:not([disabled])');
            if ($(checkboxes).length > $(checkboxes + ':checked').length) {
                $(checkboxes).attr('checked', 'checked').closest('li').attr('checked', 'checked');
            } else {
                $(checkboxes).removeAttr('checked', 'checked').closest('li').removeAttr('checked');
            }
            ($(this).text() == "Select All") ? $(this).text("Select None") : $(this).text("Select All")
            $(this).next('ul').trigger('change')
            return false;
        }))
    }

    //Write the Data to the DOM
    $(ul).data({
        heftyBox: a
    })

    //Apply DOM data
    updateheftyBox($(ul));

    //Handle Value Change
    $(this).bind('change', function() {updateheftyBox($(this));})
    }

    //scroll to first selected DOM
    if ($(ul).find('li[checked]:first').length) {
        var itemTop = $(ul).find('li[checked]:first').offset().top || $(ul).offset().top;
        var ulTop = $(ul).offset().top;
        $(ul).scrollTop(itemTop - ulTop);
    }
}

updateheftyBox = function(target) {
    var a = $(target).data().heftyBox;
    var container = $(target).parent('.heftyBox');
    var filter = $(target).siblings('.list_filter');
    var ul = $(target);

    //Gather created data
    a.value = [];
    $(ul).find('input:checked').each(function() {
        a.value.push($(this).val())
    })

    $(container).css({
        width: a.width,
        height: a.height,
        "min-width": $(filter).outerWidth()
    });
    $(ul).css({
        height: a.height - $(filter).outerHeight(),
        "margin-top": $(filter).outerHeight()
    })
    $(ul).val(a.value);
}


filterBox = function(target, blocks) {
    $(target).unbind('keyup change');
    $(target).bind('keyup change', function() {
        var inText = $(this).val().trim(); //remove trailing whitespace

        $.each(blocks, function() {
            var title = $(this).children('label').text(); //the title in the block
            if (matchAll(title, inText)) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        })

    })
}

matchAll = function(string, args) { //string= string to match, args= search input
    var die = 0; //return switch
    var checks = args.split(' '); //break input into array
    $.each(checks, function() {
        var myReg = new RegExp(this, 'i'); //search term to regex
        if (!string.match(myReg)) { //if it doesn't match, kill the function
            die = 1;
        } 
    })

    if (die == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

$('.heftyBox li:has(input:checkbox)').live('click', function() {
    ($(this).has(':checked').length) ? $(this).attr('checked', 'checked') : $(this).removeAttr('checked')
})
```

The concepts of thus plugin:

- The HeftyBox should be dynamic and not affect any attributes or user input that coould be collected by the original Select box
- The HeftyBox should accept many options to match styling and uniqueness of the application it is being used for
- The HeftyBox should be able to be modified and customized with calls to the object after it is initiated
- The HefyBox should be easy to implement, attractive, and functional with defualt setting

Source [github/kmacey1249/heftybox](https://github.com/kmacey1249/heftybox)

Implemented like so:

Initial HTML

```
<select name="test" id="test" multiple="multiple" bar="baz">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3" foo="bar">Three</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Call

`$('#test').heftyBox(); //{type: "checkbox"/"radio", width: "auto", height: 150}`

Result:

```
<div class="heftyBox" id="test_container" style="width: auto; height: 178px; min-width: 155px; ">
  <input id="test_filter" class="list_filter" />
  <a href="#">Select All</a>
  <ul id="test" multiple="multiple" bar="baz" style="height: 155px; margin-top: 23px; ">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option_test_0" name="test" value="1">
      <label for="option_test_0">One</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option_test_1" name="test" value="2">
      <label for="option_test_1">Two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option_test_2" name="test" value="3" foo="bar">
      <label for="option_test_2">Three</label>
    </li>           
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: plugin preview]

Code in action at JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kmacey1249/vXGke/

Comment: Can you give us an use case, some HTML which one it will work. It'll be more easy to see how it works and what it is doing. I already can see some optimization but with an use case, it will help us to review.

Comment: Updated with example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments in the code that explain why I did some things.

Here is the result of my refactoring:

- Putting the code in a self-executing function. Your three helpers functions don't have to be in the global scope.
- Caching almost all elements. You made too many calls to `$`
- Adding a lot of semicolons which you forgot to use
- Used plain JavaScript instead of the equivalent jQuery function (`attr()`, `val()`, etc.)
- Stopped relying on id's. You were inserting elements and then using the DOM to retrieve them by ID. I just created elements, then inserted them.

**Edit** : I just added another closure function because the first wasn't taking `$.fb.heftyBox` into it's closure.

PS: Setting invalid attributes for a tag is not a good solution. Use 'data-' attributes instead of putting invalid attributes in a tag.

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.heftyBox = (function() {
    // usefull functions
    // declared in a self-executing function to not charge the global scope

    var updateheftyBox = function($target) {
        // $target is already a jQuery object, don't need to $() it again
        var box         = $target.data().heftyBox,
            $container  = $target.parent('.heftyBox'),
            $filter     = $target.siblings('.list_filter'); // caching $(filter)

        //Gather created data
        box.value = [];
        $target.find('input:checked').each(function() {
            // using this.value instead of .val(), jQuery tools is not needed
            box.value.push(this.value); 
        });

        $container.css({
            width: box.width,
            height: box.height,
            "min-width": $filter.outerWidth()
        });

        $target.css({
            height: box.height - $filter.outerHeight(),
            "margin-top": $filter.outerHeight()
        })
        $target.val(box.value);
    };


    var filterBox = function($target, blocks) {
        // $target is already a jQuery object, don't need to $() it again

        // use chaining
        $target.unbind('keyup change')
            .bind('keyup change', function() {
                // input, don't need to use $(this).val(), just this.value
                var inText = this.value.trim(); //remove trailing whitespace

                $.each(blocks, function() {
                    var $that = $(this);
                    var title = $that.children('label').text(); //the title in the block
                    if (matchAll(title, inText)) {
                        $that.show();
                    } else {
                        $that.hide();
                    }
                });

            });
    };

    var matchAll = function(string, args) { //string= string to match, args= search input
        var checks = args.split(' '); //break input into array
        for(var i = checks.length; i--; ) {
            if (!string.match(new RegExp(checks[i], 'i'))) { // test if args[i] match the string
                // return false if one don't match, don't need to get threw all
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true;
    };



    return function(args) {
        var $that = $(this);
        if ($that.length) {
            //Set up defaults
            var opt = $.extend({
                        type   :  "checkbox",
                        width  :  "auto",
                        height :  ($that.innerHeight() > 150) ? $that.innerHeight() : 150
                    }, args
                ),
                attributes = $that[0].attributes, //Gather original attributes, convert DOM, then reassgign attributes
                optionsHTML = $that.html();
                $ul = $('<ul id="tmpul">' + optionsHTML + '</ul>'); // build ul, then use it | maybe use a random id instead of hardcoding one

            for (var i = attributes.length; i--; ) {
                $ul.attr(attributes[i].name, attributes[i].value);
            }


            //Convert options to checkbox or radios
            var options = $ul.children('option'),
                name = $ul.attr('name'),
                f = 0;
            $ul.removeAttr('name'),

            $.each(options, function(key, option) {
                var $that           = $(this),
                    itemAttributes  = $that[0].attributes,
                    value           = $that.value,
                    label           = $that.text(),
                    selected        = itemAttributes.selected ? "checked" : '';

                selected += itemAttributes.disabled ? " disabled" : '';

                var $newLi = $('<li ' + selected + '></li>'), 
                    $input = $('<input type="' + opt.type + '" id="option_' + name + '_' + f + '" name="' + name + '" value="' + value + '" ' + selected + '/><label for="option_' + name + '_' + f + '">' + label + '</label>');
                $newLi.append($input);
                $that.replaceWith($newLi);
                for (var i = attributes.length; i--; ) {
                    $input[0][attributes[i].name] = attributes[i].value;
                }

                f++;
            });

            //Add Filter Box
            var $filter = $('<input id="' + name + '_filter" class="list_filter" />');
            var list = $ul.children('li');
            filterBox($filter, list);

            // add filter and ul to new container
            var $container = $('<div class="heftyBox" id="' + name + '_container"></div>').append($filter, $ul);
            // replace existing element by new container
            $that.after($container).remove();

            //Select all box for checkboxes
            if (opt.type == "checkbox") {
                var $link = $('<a href="#">Select All</a>')
                        .bind('click', function() {
                            var $that = $(this);
                            //@todo get checked
                            // directly using $ul not using specific dom manipulation
                            var $checkboxes = $ul.find('input:not([disabled])');

                            // btw... adding 'checked' attribute to an li is weird... maybe using a data-checked will be better
                            if ($checkboxes.length > $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length) {
                                $checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked').closest('li').attr('checked', 'checked');
                            } else {
                                $checkboxes.removeAttr('checked').closest('li').removeAttr('checked');
                            }

                            $that.text( ($that.text() == "Select All") ? "Select None" : "Select All");
                            $ul.trigger('change');
                            return false;
                        }
                    );
                // divided creating and appending. just take one more line and is more readable
                $filter.after($link);
            }

            //Write the Data to the DOM
            $ul.data({ heftyBox: opt });

            //Apply DOM data
            updateheftyBox($ul);

            //Handle Value Change
            $ul.bind('change', function() { updateheftyBox($(this)); }) // change event when clickin
                .delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function() { // delegate click event on checkbox
                    var li = $(this).parent();
                    (this.checked) ? li.attr('checked', 'checked') : li.removeAttr('checked');

                    // trigger change
                    $ul.trigger('change');
                });

            //scroll to first selected DOM
            if ($ul.find('li[checked]:first').length) {
                var itemTop = $ul.find('li[checked]:first').offset().top || $ul.offset().top,
                    ulTop = $ul.offset().top;
                $ul.scrollTop(itemTop - ulTop);
            }
        }

    };
    })();
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, I copied your code into a separate branch on the GitHub and will try refactoring on my own with the advice I get here, then determine the best end result to merge.

Answer (score 2):

Well I forked it and will work on a refactoring but some comments:

- Cache variables so that you don't have to keep invoking `$()` - it is common to do `var $this = $(this);`
- Don't use ids. They are a host of problems. What if there are 2 hefty boxes on a page? Or worse, what if my app uses one of those names? You virtually never need to do that
- I prefer using `$.each` to `for` loops - they are safer and the performance hit is unlikely to hurt you in this case. In any case you should cache the length since `arr.length` is recalculated at every invocation.
- [About `return false`](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)
- Enclose the same thing in an immediately executing function that makes usage of $ safe

  ```
  (function($) {
    // your code
  })(jQuery);
  ```
- When you're using jquery to create elements, you don't have to include the closing one.
- Also, include tests or at least a test page - I will have a hard time testing out my fork.
- Also I see this pattern a lot:

  $(filter).before('<div class="heftyBox" id="' + name + '_container"></div>');
  var container = $('#' + name + '_container');

  **This will break** if there's another heftybox before this or if they didn't include a name or for a million other reasons. Here is a much better approach:

  var container = $('<div class="heftyBox" id="' + name + '_container"').after(filter);

  Or at he very least use jQuery's `next` and `prev` methods.

Comment: jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kmacey1249/vXGke/

Comment: @KyleMacey Updated my answer with a few more items that I saw prevelant.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is why I posted here. I've been able to make code work well for specific instances, but needed a good line of correction to nail out best practices and making my code universal.